# Syntax Error: Passing AJAX success data to append HTML tag's function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I don't come up exact title, but this is easy to understand if see below image.

[image]

I want to use `ajax success data(result)` to tag's function parameter of append(). I tried to several ways but always occur syntax error.

I tried.

```
#1 <button onclick=deleteRow(this, '+result+')>Button</button>
// SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

#2 <button onclick="deleteRow(this, '+result+')">Button</button>
// SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

#3 <button onclick="deleteRow(this, this.result)">Button</button>
// this.result is undefined

#4 <button onclick="deleteRow(this, "+result+")">Button</button>
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

#5 <button onclick="deleteRow(this, result)">Button</button>
// result is just result, doesn't get success return data
```

How can I do that?

Comment: DON"T add screenshot of code. Add actual code.

Comment: Wrap the `result` in quotes. `onclick=deleteRow(this, "' + result + '")`

Comment: I'll suggest to use `on('click', function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using whole result object, use some property of it like this:

```
onclick=deleteRow(this, ' + (result.id) + ')
```

Here I appended id field, you can append any other property as required and if that property is string do something like this:

```
onclick=deleteRow(this, "' + (result.id) + '")
```